# Why some Titanium/Android code needs hacks like setTimeout to function properly?

Tags: android, titanium, settimeout

I've noticed that sometimes I have to enclose my Titanium/Android javascript code into a setTimeout call so that code gets executed.
I don't understand why some lines of code are completely ignored sometimes, and when I add a setTimeout of 500ms to then, so they get executed.
Examples, I've gathered from the Internet:

//alloy_fugitive App: [alloy_fugitive](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/alloy_fugitive/blob/d6e59904719dcc7d61f9af7f0617b68c62ac5fd2/app/controllers/FugitiveDetail.js)

```
//on android, give a bit of a delay before closing the window...
    if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.detailWindow.close();
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        $.detailWindow.close();
    }
```

//cloudpush code: [tidev.io](http://www.tidev.io/2013/12/20/using-gcm-for-android-push-notifications-with-acs/)

```
CloudPush.enabled = !CloudPush.enabled;
// NOTE: Push.enabled takes a moment to update after you change its value.
setTimeout(syncButtons, 500);
```

//my code derived from Codestrong App:

```
function startRefresh() {
    $.home.add($.loading.getView());
    $.loading.start();
    loadContent();
    $.loading.stop();
    //dont know why android needs time...
    setTimeout(function (){$.home.remove($.loading.getView());}, 500);
}
```

What really annoys me is the fact that I never know when code will fail without warning, what leads me to endless debug sessions.

**Am I missing something here?
Any place where those caveats and gotchas are documented?
Is Titanium so buggy?**

Answer (score 0):

Titanium is based on JavaScript language which requires writing asynchronous code.

In one of your examples you write:

```
$.loading.start();
loadContent();
$.loading.stop();
```

You can't be sure that all operations called in `loadContent()` have been finished before you call `$.loading.stop()`. If you are calling any asynchronous function you have to provide callback with code which will be executed when operation finishes.

Comment: Yes, but, like in the fugitives example, you dont have to wait anything if your platform is IOS !

Comment: Actually, on the code above, `loadContent()` is an empty function and `$.loading` is a Ti.UI.imageView and `start()`or `stop()` are simply functions for imageView.start and imageView.stop.  ===> Looks like if I start a imageView animation I cannot stop it immediatelly. That is so obscure... ==> may be because of that proxy stuff in Titanium, the framework cannot have control after proxying things down below....